# how to move items to another component by click - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was wondering how can I move my items -> book, from one component to another. I took this books from api and I show them in the list, so I have an ID.

```
<template>
<v-flex v-for="(book, index) in allBooks">
 <div>Title: {{ book.title }}</div>
 <i @click="markAsFavorite(book)" :class="{isActive: isMark}" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
</template>

//component books

<script>
  name: 'Books',
   data () {
     return {
      allBooks: [],
      isMark: false,
      favouriteBooks: []
    }
 },

  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=id:" + this.id)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.allBooks = response.data.items.map(item => ({...item, isMark: false}))
            console.log(this.allBooks)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
  },

   methods: {       
     markAsFavorite(book) {
       this.isMark = !this.isMark
       let favouriteAllBooks = this.favouriteBooks.push(book => { 
        book.id = // i dont know what?
    })
   },
  }
</script>

//component favourite

<template>
    <div class=showFavouriteBook>
      <p></p>
    </div>

</template>
```

I tried to compare this marked book ID to something, and then this array with marked books show in second template `favourite`. But I have no idea how to do this. Maybe somebody can prompt me something?

Comment: by saying "from one component to another", you mean child component or what ? if you mean children components, then you can just pass a prop into the component [https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html]. However if you want to pass to another independent component, you might try [https://vuex.vuejs.org/] which is basically global storage that allows you to access any variable anywhere

Comment: Instead of `let favouriteAllBooks = this.favouriteBooks.push(book => { book.id = ...`  just do `this.favouriteBooks.push(book)` and of-course just do as @user8555937 says. If you app is going to be big, then use Axios - a library to manage app state.

Comment: @Syed Axios **does not** manage app state; (unless you refer to another axios package): https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 2):

You should use a global eventBus for that. An 'eventBus' is another instance of Vue which is used to pass data via components tied to the main application.

At the root script of your application append the following:

```
const eventBus = new Vue({
    data: function() {
        return {
            some_var: null,
        }
    }
});
```

You can use Vue mixin to have your event bus accessible globally easily:

```
Vue.mixin({
    data: function() {
        return {
            eventBus: eventBus,
        }
    }
});
```

---

Now when you want to pass data between components you can use the bus:

**Component 1**

```
// for the sake of demo I'll use mounted method, which is invoked each time component is mounted
<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            this.eventBus.some_var = 'it works!'
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Component 2**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ eventBus.some_var }} <!-- it works -->
    </div>
</template>
```

---

In addition you can use [$emit and $on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

**Component 1**

```
// for the sake of demo I'll use mounted method, which is invoked each time component is mounted
<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            // emit 'emittedVarValue' event with parameter 'it works'
            this.eventBus.$emit('emittedVarValue', 'it works!')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Component 2**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ some_var }} <!-- "it works" once eventBus receives event "emittedVarValue" -->
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                some_var: null
            }
        },

        mounted: function() {
            // waiting for "emittedVarValue" event
            this.eventBus.$on('emittedVarValue', (data)=>{
                this.some_var = data;
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: thank you for that. I will try to use this event :)